# using video.js with adtech adserver

Tags: video.js, advertisement-server

Is there any documentation (or can you explain) how to use Video.js with Adtech ad-server (we're trying to call video ads through video.js player to an hybrid moblie app).

Thanks!

Elad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming AdTech provides a standard VAST response you should be able to use of these plugins.

- https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima
- https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin